# connect remote host without password in linux

Tags: linux, ssh

Am trying to connect remote host by using ssh:

```
ssh xxxx@hostname.
```

It will connect by asking password.

But I need to connect host with out password.

Comment: I can understand you don't know how to remove a password, or how to allow empty passwords while using ssh, but to miss out on setting up private/public keys means to me you did not put in any effort and at all. We are willing to help with misunderstandings or problems, but there has to be some show of effort, or else my recommendation will be to hire a competent system admin.

Answer (score 0):

Use public/private keys. To do that you will need to generate a key using `ssh-keygen` (man for the documentation) once you have generated the key you will have (assuming you have generated an rsa key) and id_rsa file (your private key) and an id_rsa.pub (your public key) copy the public key to /home/xxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys. Now you will be able to log in without a password.